# Stripe payment gateway not working after Installing certbot ssl certificate in django site

Tags: python, django, ssl, stripe-payments, payment

Stripe payment gateway in my django website was working fine but after installing certbot ssl certificate Stripe payment gateway not working. I am getting error  -  No api proxy found for service "urlfetch". [you can see error in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPD0i.png)

do I need to change payment gateway???

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

not possible beacuse you are doing in wrong way brother

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).